# STM32L1 USART interrupt problem

Tags: arm, uart, stm32

I am trying to use stm32l152 discovery kit to communicate by using usart. Although I can send data on tx (I check this via pc), I couldn't get in interrupt function when data come (I send via pc and also make tx and rx short circuit and debug). main.c file is like below. I tried and examine a lot of example on the internet (even not related directly stm32l1 to understand what is going on with arm) but I couldn't find the problem. What could be the problem?

By the way, I am using IAR as IDE. When I add breakpoint inside to interrupt function (USART3_IRQHandler) and run, IAR alert -One or more breakpoints could not be set and have been disabled- and disable breakpoint inside interrupt function.

```
#include "main.h"


void DelaySW(uint32_t delay);
void RCC_Config(void);
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure; 
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;   
USART_ClockInitTypeDef USART_ClockInitstructure;    
uint16_t receivedData;


void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART3,USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
    USART_SendData(USART3, 'c');
  }    
}


int main(void)
{
  RCC_Config();

  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

  /* Alternate function conf */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART3 );
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_USART3 );
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_USART3 );
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_USART3 );
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_USART3 );


  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 | GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_40MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);


  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART3_IRQn;
  NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_0);
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;

  USART_ClockInitstructure.USART_Clock   = USART_Clock_Disable ;
  USART_ClockInitstructure.USART_CPOL    = USART_CPOL_Low ;
  USART_ClockInitstructure.USART_LastBit = USART_LastBit_Enable;
  USART_ClockInitstructure.USART_CPHA    = USART_CPHA_1Edge;


  /* USART conf */

  USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 9600;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;


  USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);
  USART_ITConfig(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE); 
  USART_ClockInit(USART3, &USART_ClockInitstructure);
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure); 


  USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);

  while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART3,USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
  USART_SendData(USART3, 'c');
  while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART3,USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
  USART_SendData(USART3, 'c');
  while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART3,USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
  USART_SendData(USART3, 'c');
  while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART3,USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
  USART_SendData(USART3, 'c');
  while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART3,USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
  USART_SendData(USART3, 'c');
    while(1);
}

void DelaySW(uint32_t delay)
{
  uint32_t i=10000;

  for(;delay > 0; delay--){
  for(;i>0;i--)
  ;
  }
}

void RCC_Config(void)
{ 
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_PWR, ENABLE);

  /* Allow access to the RTC */
  PWR_RTCAccessCmd(ENABLE);

  /* Reset Backup Domain */
  RCC_RTCResetCmd(ENABLE);
  RCC_RTCResetCmd(DISABLE);

  /*!< LSE Enable */
  RCC_LSEConfig(RCC_LSE_ON);

  /*!< Wait till LSE is ready */
  while (RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_LSERDY) == RESET)
  {}
  /*!< LCD Clock Source Selection */
  RCC_RTCCLKConfig(RCC_RTCCLKSource_LSE);
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

  /**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
  void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
  {
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1);
  }

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the linker is not behaving properly.

Each IDE has its own way of dealing with interrupts, but usually there is a file somewhere named "something_that_contains_interrupts.c" with all the declarations of the interrupt functions. The programmer just need to fill in his/her own code and the linker takes care of the rest.

Giving the function the correct name is certainly a good start, but seeing that you only included "main.h" I'm pretty sure that's not eonugh.

What is happening now is that the compiler is smart enough to understand that "USART3_IRQHandler" is never called, so it does not actually compile it, so it is clearly impossible to add a breakpoint in a piece of code that does not exist.

Just try to call the ISR once in your main, if IAR stops complaining I am probably right. Keep in mind that you have a while(1); statement in the function, so nothing else is gonna work, you'll just have your working breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just included main.h but in it also stm32l1xx.h, stm32l1xx_conf.h and <stdio.h> are included. Additionally, there isn't any error while compiling.If there is lack of including file, IAR would throw error,I guess. Wouldn't it?
You are right about breakpoint disabling issue. IAR didn't compile USART3_IRQHandler function. So, I called it in main function just before "while(1);" and made short circuit tx and rx. I expected that after first USART_SendData, it get in interrupt, but it didn't happen.
Lastly, I didn't understand why IAR doesn't recognize interrupt function?

Comment: It would not throw any error at all, it might just think "why is this guy writing down a function and never using it? whatever". My point is that as things are now the linker can't know that this function is an ISR. Try to search around in your project tree if there's a source file that seems to deal with interrupts, or, way better, read a tutorial or something about IAR on how to implement interrupts on your platform.